# assigning write permissions to /proc/sys/vm in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I asked my sysadmin if he can do the following:

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode`

He came back to me saying that he doesn't have the necessary permissions (as root) to create a file in that directory (vm) and that directory doesn't have write permissions set (only has xr) and also that he cannot change the permissions. He tried adding write permission to vm directory but that operation failed.

How can we add write permissions to that directory and create the required file?

Its Ubuntu 9.04

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am posting this here again on the suggestion from my [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491464/assigning-write-permission-to-proc-sys-vm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vm.zone_reclaim_mode` setting should be handled by using `sysctl(8)`, and not by writing to the `/proc` filesystem directly:

```
# sysctl -a | grep zone_reclaim_mode
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0

# sysctl -w vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 1
```

You can write your customizations to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file to make persistent changes.

Comment: Thank you. zone_reclaim_mode is not present in vm directory, so when I grep for it, it doesn't find it. I guess we need to put `vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 1` in /etc/sysctl.conf?

Comment: As explained above, don't try to fiddle with this settings directly using the `/proc` filesystem. Have you tried the commands I posted?

Comment: Yes I did. The grep does not return anything because it is not present (also not present in the vm directory). (Consequently?) `sysctl -w vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1` returns an error -- `error: "vm.zone_reclaim_mode" is an unknown key`. That is why I asked if we should put this assignment in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file itself? I guess, it would come into affect only after a system reboot?

Comment: Is this a physical server or some VPS?

Comment: Its a physical server

Comment: As per [the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt), `zone_reclaim_mode` has been present since 2.6.29.

Comment: I checked the kernel version and it is 2.6.28-11-server. Does this mean setting or not setting of `zone_reclaim_mode` has no affect?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04 is ancient. Update your OS and get rid of this problem altogether.

Comment: Ok. I would ask my admin to update it. One last question :) -- do you know how pre 2.6.29 versions handle the same functionality as that provided by zone_reclaim_mode?

Comment: Nope, sorry. You'll need to look that up in kernel.org.

Answer (score 3):

Under `/proc` you usually find the proc pseudo file system. Its not an actual file system that stores data on a persistent storage device, but a way for the kernel to display settings to the userspace. Reading/writing to these files communicates with the kernel. If your kernel supports the `zone_reclaim_mode` setting (and proc is mounted correctly) then reading from the file `/proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode` gives you the current setting, and writing to `/proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode` tells the kernel that you want to change the setting. If your kernel isn't configured to show the setting then you can't just create a new file here, that wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. zone_reclaim_mode isn't already present there. So the only way is to unmount it and then remounting it correctly is it?

Answer (score 1):

Add `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1` to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
echo "vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then tell sysctl to reread it

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```