# assigning write permission to /proc/sys/vm

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I asked my sysadmin if he can do the following:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
```

He came back to me saying that he doesn't have the necessary permissions (as root) to create a file in that directory (vm) and that directory doesn't have write permissions (only has xr) and also that he cannot change the permissions. He tried adding write permission to vm directory but that operation failed.

How can we add write permissions to that directory and create the required file?

This seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861880/programmatically-drop-linux-cache-as-non-root-user)?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Posted this on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/535328/assigning-write-permissions-to-proc-sys-vm-in-ubuntu) as well. Thanks to the admin for moving the post, but I have already made a post (instead of waiting for a week) on serverfault as indicated in the link here.

Comment: The system is the only one who can create files in the directory since it contains only virtual files that let you look at and modify certain system settings. Reference @ott answer and http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-proc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the admin set `vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, this way it will be set on every reboot. Then he should run `sysctl -p` to activate the new setting for the running system.

Comment: Use sysctl for persistence. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt End of page for documentation on that command. Another Reference: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaat%2Fliaattunsetzonereclaim.htm

Comment: Thank you. From this reply and from the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/535328/assigning-write-permissions-to-proc-sys-vm-in-ubuntu (same post), I understood about /proc contents a bit more. However, as indicated in the comments of that answer, `zone_reclaim_mode` is from server 2.6.29 and we are using 2.6.28. Do you know how the functionality of this flag is achieved in pre 2.6.29 versions?

Comment: @Raghava Depends of your version. At least it's in version 2.6.28.10 - that's where I saw it.

Comment: @ott--, The kernel version we use is 2.6.28-11-server

Comment: I've looked into the first 2.6.28, and it was already present there, too. So it should be working.

Answer (score -1):

Use the command

```
sudo chmod 744 /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
```

That will give the file owner (which I'm assuming is root) read/write/execute permissions, and will give everyone else read permissions. If root is NOT the owner, you can make root the owner with

```
sudo chown root /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
```

But as a warning, be careful, this directory may not be write-able for a reason!

EDIT: changed 711 to 744

Comment: The sysadmin already tried using chmod but that did not change the file permissions it seems.

Comment: Warning: `0711` is NOT `rwxr--r--`, as this answer advertises, it is `rwx--x--x` - everyone can execute, no one but owner can read. If reading this file is important to anyone but root, you must use `744`

Comment: woops, thanks for the correction, Dan, I'll edit the answer

Comment: What kind of filesystem is it? If you don't know, look under the "Type" column after executing "df -T" from the command line

Comment: thank you. I would request the moderator to move the post over.

Comment: You should never need to chmod anything in the proc filesystem. It is a virtual filesystem and can not be modified in that scenario and should be controlled using the appropriate system commands. Reference: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-proc.html